# Create object starting from a list of string with jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I would like to create a json object starting with a list of string in json format as the following

```json
[
  "nonprod/global/app/sit01",
  "nonprod/global/app/dev02",
  "prod/na/app/prod01",
  "test/eu/app/cust01",
  "nonprod/global/app/dev03"
]
```

What I would like to obtain is a map of lists of strings which would have as key the first two words of the string from the list and as value the strings that starts with that specific key.

I've tried the following:

```
jq 'reduce (.[] | capture("(?<env_type>([^/]*/[^/]*))").env_type as $key | {($key) : [.]}) as $item ({}; . *= $item)'
```

And obtained:

```json
{
  "nonprod/global": [
    "nonprod/global/app/dev03"
  ],
  "prod/na": [
    "prod/na/app/prod01"
  ],
  "test/eu": [
    "test/eu/app/cust01"
  ],
  "prod/eu": [
    "prod/eu/app/prod01"
  ]
}
```

I'm expecting:

```json
{
  "nonprod/global":[
    "nonprod/global/app/sit01",
    "nonprod/global/app/dev02",
    "nonprod/global/app/dev03"
  ],
  "prod/eu":[
    "prod/eu/app/prod01"
  ],
  
  "prod/na":[
    "prod/na/app/prod01"
  ],
  "test/eu":[
    "test/eu/app/cust01"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+=` to add to an array. If the key doesn't exist, jq will create it on the fly (`null + []` evaluates to `[]`):

```bash
reduce (.[] | capture("^(?<env>(?<type>[^/]*/[^/]*).*)$")) as {$env, $type} 
({}; .[$type] += [$env])
```

```json
{
  "nonprod/global": [
    "nonprod/global/app/sit01",
    "nonprod/global/app/dev02",
    "nonprod/global/app/dev03"
  ],
  "prod/na": [
    "prod/na/app/prod01"
  ],
  "test/eu": [
    "test/eu/app/cust01"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/72TIrzt9VIC)

Comment: Nice, thanks.
Mind to explain a bit how reduce works? From the docs I cannot see a lot of details on how it works and by knowing this I could probably have a much easier life in the future.

Comment: @Maonat `reduce x as $a (init; step)` starts out with the initial state "init", then iterates over each "x", assigns it to variable "$a" which is visible in "step", which in turn generates a new state. The last state generated is the result of the `reduce` filter. In this example, we start out with `{}`, and each step adds an array item `$env` to the array under key `$type`. These variables are set as defined by `capture`, which gets its input from iterating over the input array.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to change slightly the required outcome to have the following outcome but wasn't successful: [{"sub":"nonprod/global","envs":["nonprod/global/app/sit01","nonprod/global/app/dev02","nonprod/global/app/dev03"]}, {second_object}, ... ]
I've tried using the following but I still cannot make an output comma separated:
`jq '[.[] | capture("^(?<env>(?<sub>[^/]*/[^/]*).*)$")] | group_by(.sub)[] | [{"sub":(.[0].sub), "envs":[.[] | .env]}]'`
Any thoughts?

Comment: @Maonat If I understand correctly, you want to turn the object back into an array, with each field turned into a separate object carrying key and value under given fields. With this approach, append `to_entries | map({sub:.key, envs:.value})` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RHlWxBXUFOh)), with my other approach, change `INDEX(…)` to `map({sub: first|f, envs: .})` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DIFtDKiQ8rT)).

Answer (score 2):

> which would have as key the first two words

You can `def`ine a function that splits at the second slash, then usi it to `group_by` the input array, creating an array of arrays, then use `INDEX` to turn it into an object, using the same function on the `first` item.

```bash
def f: .[:indices("/")[1]];
group_by(f) | INDEX(first | f)
```

```json
{
  "nonprod/global": [
    "nonprod/global/app/sit01",
    "nonprod/global/app/dev02",
    "nonprod/global/app/dev03"
  ],
  "prod/na": [
    "prod/na/app/prod01"
  ],
  "test/eu": [
    "test/eu/app/cust01"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nhDPe1J691H)